# Diagramming tool that reduces crossed lines

Tags: diagrams

I'm trying to represent "dependency" relationships between a large number of objects.

I don't want to have to bother with arranging where all the boxes sit on the screen, and having to reposition them every time I add an additional arrow.

I want to just type in the entities and specify the relationships, and as I do so, have the software shuffle everything around on the screen, in the most presentable way.

E.g. With the fewest number of crossing lines.

Is there any tool on the market that does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [yEd Graph Editor](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html). It can automatically re-arrange layouts in a wide variety of methods: hierarchical, organic, orthogonal, circular, tree, random, etc.

It can import nodes and relationships from Excel from several other formats.

It is also free.

**Edit:**

I should state that yEd won't automatically rearrange nodes *as you enter them*. You must select the action from a menu or with keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: How do we use yEd to select the "no overlapping lines" option?

Answer (score 3):

No. But there's [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585422/simple-linear-arrangement-in-graphviz